# Android scrollbar height with Recyclerview

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with a list of objects. The scrollbar has an height of about 2 items I need to set this with an height of 1 item. How could I change the lenght/height of my scrollbar?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tinbytes.samples.showhidetoolbar.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Friends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of my problem :

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing what you are trying to do, the scrollbar is not a set height/length. It is dynamic based on the size of the scrolling content.

Comment: @dharms as you can see the height/lenght of my scrollbar is about 2 items and a piece. How could I fix?

Comment: I don't understand what is needing to be fixed... The scrollbar will change size based on the number of items in the view.

Comment: @dharms If you have "Whatsapp" check the scrollbar's size. The height/lenght will be the same of the single item.